# Error while importing sql - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: mysql, sql, import

I am trying to import an sql file which shows me the following error:

```
Error
SQL query:

-- --------------------------------------------------------
--
-- Table structure for table `users`
--
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `users` (

 `uid` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `uemail` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `upassword` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uname` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uemailh` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uclass` TINYTEXT NOT NULL ,
 `regno` VARCHAR( 8 ) NOT NULL ,
 `absencecount` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  'a:10:{i:0;i:0;i:1;i:0;i:2;i:0;i:3;i:0;i:4;i:0;i:5;i:0;i:6;i:0;i:7;i:0;i:8;i:0;i:9;i:0;}',
 `internalmarks` VARCHAR( 500 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  's:73:"["0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]";',
PRIMARY KEY (  `uid` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `uemail` (  `uemail` ,  `uname` ) ,
KEY  `regno` (  `regno` )
) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT =2;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
```

I've tried to create a new  database in my local machine everything works fine. But, while importing it in the remote server it shows the above error. Any Idea?

Comment: What happens if you substitute `VARCHAR( 500 )` with `VARCHAR( 255 )` ?

Comment: I'm guessing your local machine is a 64-bit system, whereas the remote  server is not. See the following link for guidelines about InnoDB key restrictions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would two people with different names (uname) have the same email address (uemail)? An email address by itself should be a unique key, I think.

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for your help. But, it didn't worked

Comment: @Gowtham show your setups (both local and remote)

Comment: @TimBurch I'm running a 32-bit Windows 7 and 64-bit Ubuntu and I tested in both of them and two hosting services. That didn't worked.

Comment: @Alexander I'm using XAMPP in my local machine and heliohost for my remote hosting.

Comment: It is answered in DBA Stackexchange:
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59037/error-while-importing-sql-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-b